# Jquery : How to assign the search result to an input?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, autocomplete

I want to assign my search result to my input's value (autocomplete) when I click one of the results. How can I do it? My working code is below.

HTML (index.php)

```
<span id="box">       
<label for="search_box">Type the writer's name</label>  
<input type="text" name="book_writer_name" id="book-writer-name">                   
</span>                    
<div id="search_result"></div>
<script src="/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery (edit.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var left = $('#box').position().left;
    var top = $('#box').position().top;
    var width = $('#box').width();

    $('#search_result').css('left', left).css('top', top + 32).css('width', width);

    $('#book-writer-name').keyup(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
        if(value != '') {
            $.post('search.php', {value:value}, function(data) {
                $('#search_result').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (search.php)

```
require('../../../cn/connect.php');
$value = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqli, $value);
$query = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT writer_name from writer where writer_name like '$value%' LIMIT 20");
while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $writer_name = $run['writer_name'];
    echo '<a href=#>'.$writer_name.'</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: Do you want do create autocomplete? :-) Maybe do you want to try http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and here check demo examples http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I forgot adding jquery files in my example code, so how do you supposed to know what I was trying to do? My mistake. I hope it became clearer now. The code above works, but I can't make my script auto complete my search box when I clicked one of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to document ready part :

```
$('#search_result').on('click', 'a', function(){
     $('#book-writer-name').val($(this).text());
});
```

If I understood well you are trying to add value to input field after clicking on link from result.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I think I've got a long way to go. :)